# Require a match with Angular-Strap typeahead

Tags: angularjs, typeahead, angular-strap

Is there a way to require that the user only enter a value which matches one of the values in the ng-options array, similar to a select element?   I guess I'm looking for a combination of typeahead and select.  The Chosen javascript plugin does this but I have had issues with that plugin with AngularJs 1.3.

Comment: I cannot directly solve your issue with Angular-Strap but I can suggest an alternate widget that does have the option to set that selection / input that matches a value in the list if required. https://github.com/EnzeyNet/AutoComplete

Comment: Thanks, @Enzey.  Your widget looks interesting, I will try it out.